# -ms-touch-action:none not working on webbrowser control wp8

Tags: windows, html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to load a html with -ms-touch-action:none defined on the body class inside a web browser control(Windows Phone app).
But still I can scroll and zoom the page.
Is there any setting of web brwser control to load html 5 css

Answer (score 0):

@-ms-viewport { min-zoom: 1; max-zoom: 1; user-zoom: fixed; }